# How to set selected color as pen color?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a pixel art painter tool in HTML and I want to add a colour picker and have it set the picked colour to the colour you're painting with.

HTML:

```
<label for="colorpicker">Color Picker:</label>
 <input type="color" id="colorpicker" value="#0000ff">
```

JS:

```
var penColour = 'black';
    
  function setPenColour(pen)
  {
    penColour = pen;
  }

  function setPixelColour(pixel)
  {
    pixel.style.backgroundColor = penColour;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select the input in js and retrieve its value:

```
let penColour = 'black';
const picker = document.getElementById("colorpicker");
    
function setPenColour() {
  penColour = picker.value;
}
  
function setPixelColour(pixel) {
  pixel.style.backgroundColor = penColour;
}
```

See more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color)

What you also may want to do is to listen to change events of the color picker to not manually update "penColour"

```
picker.addEventListener("change", (ev) => {
  penColour = ev.value;
})
```